# numpy exponentiation with ** on integer array vs float array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, precision, exponentiation

Why do I get a difference between `**` operating on a float array and on an integer array?

1. What is `**` doing differently on the integer array than on a float array?
2. Is this some sort of a rounding problem with machine precision?
3. And why is it only an issue with an array and not when I type it out?

MWE: why is `f(ns)` not equal `f(fs)`

```
import numpy as np
def f(x):
    a = +x**5
    b = +x**6 
    return a-b

ns = np.array([60])   #integers
fs = np.array([60.])  #floats

print(ns)
print(fs)

print(f(ns))
print(f(fs))

print(int(60)**5- int(60)**6)
print(60.**5 - 60.**6)
```

resulting in

```
[60]
[60.]

[1366240256]
[-4.58784e+10]

-45878400000
-45878400000.0
```

Comment: What are the exact dtypes?

Comment: Presumably you are running on Windows or some other platform where the default integer size is 32 bits.  Take a close look at `np.array([60])**6`.  The integer calculation overflows the maximum 32 bit integer and "wraps around" to a negative value.  (Anyone on a platform where the default integer is 64 bit can see the effect with `np.array([60], dtype=np.int32)**6`.)

Comment: `print(f(ns))` gives `[-45878400000]` on my 64-bit linux system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `np.int32` and `int` are different things. In other words, elements of numpy integer array are not Python integers.

In Python, `int` is an arbitrary length integer.  You may calculate `123**45` and get a 90+ digit integer number, which is exactly `123**45` .

In numpy, elements of array are standard 32-bit or 64-bit (or sometimes 8 or 16 bit) integers, and arithmetic operators standard CPU arithmetics.  In this case, numbers are almost certainly signed or unsigned 32-bit.  So it calculates `60**6` with 32-bit integers.  Since it does not fit into 32 bits, the result is something like 60<sup>6</sup> modulo 2<sup>32</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

Your system is defaulting to `np.int32` for int types, so this is an overflow issue. You need to use `np.int64` for this to work. Observe:

```
In [3]: ns = np.array([60],dtype=np.int32)

In [4]: f(ns)
Out[4]: array([1366240256], dtype=int32)

In [5]: ns = np.array([60],dtype=np.int64)

In [6]: f(ns)
Out[6]: array([-45878400000])
```